# How do i show only one deliverydate per article?

Tags: sql

Trying to get my SQL to only show one "levdatum" per articlenumber in the second column but i can´t get in to work.

Have tried to use min och the deldate (MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(10), G02T1.deldate, 121)) but the output is the same.

[image]

Anyone who has an idea how to get this to work?

```
Select G02T1.inordno, G02T1.partno, G02T1.partdscu, CONVERT(CHAR(10), G02T1.deldate, 121) as Levdatum, ordname

from

G02T1

join G00T1 on G00T1.shortg00 = G02T1.shortg00

where G02T1.partno in ('3002583','3002584','3003122','3003293','3003333','3003335','3003546','3003586','3003596','5002017','5002018','5002450','5003368','5004721','5004723','5004724','5004803','5004804','5004805','5004806','5004807')
and G02T1.g02stat =1

group by G02T1.inordno, G02T1.partno, G02T1.partdscu, G02T1.deldate, ordname

order by G02T1.partno, G02T1.deldate
```

Comment: Please show output as text not picture. Please give table defintions and sample data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take `deldate` out of the group by and apply `max()` ( or another window function) to the expression `levdatum`

```
Select 
  G02T1.inordno, 
  G02T1.partno, 
  G02T1.partdscu, 
  CONVERT(CHAR(10), max(G02T1.deldate)) as Levdatum, 
  ordname
from
  G02T1
join G00T1 on G00T1.shortg00 = G02T1.shortg00
where G02T1.partno in ('3002583','3002584','3003122','3003293','3003333','3003335','3003546','3003586','3003596','5002017','5002018','5002450','5003368','5004721','5004723','5004724','5004803','5004804','5004805','5004806','5004807')
and G02T1.g02stat =1
group by 
  G02T1.inordno, G02T1.partno, G02T1.partdscu,  ordname
order by 
  G02T1.partno, G02T1.deldate
```

Comment: Couldn´t get the max() or min() to work by setting it after the convert and removing it from group by. Gets an error saying it needs 1 argument.

Comment: corrected : your could also try using more simply `CONVERT(CHAR(10), max(G02T1.deldate)) as Levdatum, ` with `max(G02T1.deldate) as Levdatum, `. We want to get the query returning the right data before we look at formatting.